# How do I make the object not cast a shadow but also not miss the shadow of another object?

Tags: shadows

How do I make the object not cast a shadow but also not miss the shadow of another object?[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "not miss the shadow"?

Comment: I think what's meant by that is, the blue plane should catch the shadow of the cube, but not cast its own shadow on the larger plane down below.

Comment: But the shadow on the larger plane below is the shadow of the cube, it's too small for the blue plane. And the shadow has a blue tint because of the bounced light. So the shadow is doing exactly what he wants, I guess... if not, that's why I was asking what it's supposed to be like.

Comment: I see what you mean - if you mix the middle plane with a transparent shader using "Is shadow ray" as a mix factor, it removes the shadow cast by the plane, but also allows the shadow of the cube to "pass through" it. If you do the same thing to the cube, it leaves no shadow on either object.

Comment: If you connect an RGB color directly to the material output (without a shader) for the material on the bottom plane, you can stop shadows from appearing on it - but it will be "unshaded" in all aspects, and will not receive shadows from anything. Don't know if this works for your project.

Comment: Why mix the middle plane with a _Transparent_ shader? If you disable _Ray Visibility_ > _Shadow_ in the _Object Properties_ like he did, the plane casts no shadow and let's the cube's shadow pass through, as it already does in his screenshot. That's why I'm asking what he wants to be different.

Comment: He wants the middle plane to cast no shadow, but a cube to cast a shadow on the middle plane. He does not want the shadow of the cube to pass through the middle plane, so there should be no shadows on the bottom plane at all. Basically, he wants the middle plane to "block" the shadow from the cube, while leaving no shadow of its own.

Comment: I guess you could be right. That wasn't really clear to me from his question so I hoped he could clarify that. Still you don't need the transparent setup just to let the cube's shadow pass through. The problem is for the lower plane not to receive the shadow if you still want to have it shaded by light or other objects. I suppose this can only be done with different render layers in the _Compositor_.

Comment: Yes! Exactly as Christopher Bennett said. I did what I wanted to do by rendering the layers.Why the developer removed the "do not accept shadows" function as in version 2.79, I do not understand.